# ElasticSearch: Match Field Within Query

Tags: search, elasticsearch

Searching for a string within an indexed document is simple with `match`.  What about the opposite?  I need to look for matches of a string field within a query.  For example, searching for:

```
correct horse battery staple
```

Should match a document with a field with a value of `horse battery`, and only that.  What is the query for that with ElasticSearch?

**Edit**: Here's a thread about someone wanting to do the same thing, but never received any replies: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/elasticsearch/IYDu5-0YD6E/discussion

Comment: I'm not sure about your example : are you trying to search on the fields name instead of the values it contain?

Comment: @Tom83 No, I'm trying to match the value of the field.  But I want to find the value of the field within the query string, not the query string within the field value.

Answer (score 1):

Inverted index  doesn't perform very well in knowing which **multiple terms** a document contains **exactly**. A solution found in the [definitive guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html#_contains_but_does_not_equal) was to index the term count and to query over the different possible combinations, which is very tedious.

Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309395/elasticsearch-filter-to-show-only-documents-with-values-from-list) (it's about filter, but the problematic is the same)  with more developped answers.

Comment: thanks, I guess it's just not really possible. I was able to get a working solution with percolators.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came to was to use the porcolator API.  I indexed the field value as a search query, and then matched it against a document that contained the query string.  This method is working quite well.  Here is how I'm creating the percolator:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/myindex/.percolator/model-2332 -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "name": "horse battery"
        }
    }
}'
```

And how I'm querying for it:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/myindex/model/_percolate -d '
{
    "doc": {
        "name": "correct horse battery staple"
    }
}'
```

Comment: Nice: don't hesitate to update your answer some code to illustrate this, it could be useful for someone.